# How to disable firebaseauth change when creating a new user?

Tags: android, firebase

Im using firebase in one of my projects. When the project starts for the very first time I authenticate the user anonymously and save the account data of the anoymous user in firestore. Everything the user do for example like giving something a thumb up is also saved in firestore. For some parts the user needs to sign up with email and password or with a google account and when the user sign up for the very first time he also needs to be verified with a link which is send to the users emailadress.

My issue is when Im using `firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword` the firebaseauth saves the user as current user before he is verified. In my case my plan is that a user create a new account then verify the account and when the user first log in successfully with a verified account the firebaseauth state change. I also want to give a user the opportunity to transfer every information or actions saved in firestore when the user was a anonymous user in the new verified account.
Which would be the best way to handle my plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating an account with an email and password as you have, you will be signed in as that user. To keep your current anonymous login, you should initialize a second instance of the Firebase SDK to hold the account while you verify it. The rough (untested code) steps you would need include:

1. Initialize a second instance of FirebaseApp. You can "clone" the default instance using:

```
// CreateAccountActivity.java (or similar)
FirebaseApp mDefaultApp = FirebaseApp.getInstance();
FirebaseAuth mDefaultAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

FirebaseApp mVerifierApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(mDefaultApp.getApplicationContext(), mDefaultApp.getOptions(), "verifier");
```

2. Get an instance of FirebaseAuth based on this second instance.

```
// underneath above code
FirebaseAuth mVerifierAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(mVerifierApp);
```

3. Create your user using the second instance

```
// in the submit handler for logging in with email and password of CreateAccountActivity.java
mVerifierAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .onSuccessTask(this, new SuccessContinuation<AuthResult, Void>() {
    @Override
    public Task<Void> then(AuthResult authResult) {
      // user was created, send verification email
      FirebaseUser user = authResult.getUser();
      return user.sendEmailVerification(/* ActionCodeSettings object here */);
    }
  })
  .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
      if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        // Sign in was successful and verification email was sent
        Log.d(TAG, "createNewEmailUser:send-verification-succeeded");
        // TODO: Update UI to say to check email
      } else {
        // Sign in failed/couldn't send verification email, display a message to the user.
        Log.w(TAG, "createNewEmailUser:send-verification-failure", task.getException());
        Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, "Authentication & Verification failed.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // TODO: Update UI to say something went wrong
      }
    }
  });
```

4. Handle the process of verifying the email as you desire (you could handle the code in app)
5. Once verified, link the anonymous account to the email-pass account

```
// in the event handler of "email has been verified" of CreateAccountActivity.java
AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(email, password);
mDefaultAuth.getCurrentUser() // the account of the anonymous login
  .linkWithCredential(credential)
  .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
      if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "linkWithCredential:success");
        // TODO: show accounts have been linked and then move on to use app as normal
      } else {
        Log.w(TAG, "linkWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
        Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, "Failed to link accounts.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // TODO: update UI to show error/contact us dialog
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

After the call to `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` successfully completes, the user is signed in. There is no way to change that behavior, and so there's also no way to prevent the auth state listener from firing.

If you want to require that the use verified their email address before they can sign in, you can either [check the `isEmailVerified` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_a_users_profile) before allowing them into your app, or you can use the [email link authentication provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth), which combines the act of signing in and verifying the email address.

Finally, if you want the user to keep access to their previous data when upgrading from an anonymous account, have a look at [account linking](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking), which is specifically made to allow that.